# Return Collections Counter Result as JSON with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not super familiar with Python but I'm working on a script that needs to essentially return a json object from python to PHP. The problem I'm having is the use of collections Counter and it not not being a valid JSON encode (actually won't even compile, which makes sense).

I am getting one error: `ValueError: keys must be a string`

Here is the snippet of code:

```
# Make sure items in set are all unique
items = collections.Counter(tuple(item) for item in all_items)

# Print json response
print json.dumps({ 'items': items, 'position': [rAvg, gAvg, bAvg] })
```

This is what my counter looks like:

```
Counter({(11, 11, 15): 8452, (151, 131, 153): 7336, (26, 29, 35): 7324, (83, 81, 100): 5080, (113, 106, 126): 5012, (54, 56, 61): 4627, (193, 193, 194): 3783, (13, 124, 157): 822})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON only allows keys to be strings, and your are tuples. Try:

```
items = collections.Counter(str(tuple(item)) for item in all_items)
```

or maybe

```
items = collections.Counter(str(item) for item in all_items)
```

(depending on how you'd like them formatted in JSON)

Answer (score 1):

json only allows strings ... your keys are tuples ... to resolve this make them strings

```
items = collections.Counter(tuple(item) for item in all_items)
items4json = dict(zip(map(str,items.keys()),items.values())
print json.dumps({ 'items': items, 'position': [rAvg, gAvg, bAvg] })
```

then to restore

```
import ast
read_dict = json.loads(someFileHandle.read())
items =  dict(zip(map(ast.literal_eval,items.keys()),items.values())
```